# TinyMCE invalid_elements - how to remove from HTML and from DOM

Tags: tinymce

I'm having problems with removing tags from TimyMCE. (last version)

```
invalid_elements : 'br' or valid_elements : 'p/br'
```

This delete/replace the tag on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> from html source but not from the DOM in the editor.

How can i prevent the use of invalid elements in the Editor DOM?
Simply said i want to prevent using a tag not only in the generated html source, but also in the Editor too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to have happen when someone presses <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> if you don't want the `<br>` to be used?  You can capture any `keydown` event in the editor and then choose what you want to do instead.

This TinyMCE Fiddle captures the `keydown` event and simply ignores <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.  You can certainly do something different if needed.

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/vogaab/1

***EDIT:***  Based on your comment I updated the fiddle:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/vogaab/2

...in this version I modify the event to make the `event.shiftKey` attribute false and then let the event finish as normal.  I no longer get a `<br>` but instead get a `<p>` tag whether I use <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to prevent the use of <br>, each new line should be in a <p> - i need it for pdf generation, for this the content should have the same appearance as html.